# What is mean "www.wiaakidaayd.com" in wireshark when i establish tor connection using Tor Browser?

Tags: certificate, tls

I am just get started in wireshark and tor, so please don't laugh)

When i establish connection to tor, using tor browser i saw in wireshark some unclear packet.

After SYN (9) -> SYN,ACK (10) -> ACK (11) i saw it - 12'th packet:
[image]

and it unclear for me:
[image]
does anybody tell me, what the "www.wiaakidaayd.com" and why it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the hostname that is included in the SSL/TLS certificate. Tor doesn't use it for authentication, so it's just [generated randomly](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/common/tortls.c?h=release-0.3.0#n1634).

Comment: thank a lot! i guess about it, but it was aprovment needed by someone)